# Angular: Redux and lazy loading

Tags: angular, redux

I see that this code doesn't work with a lazyloading component
Do you have any idea about it?

```
ngOnInit() {    
    this.store.select('reduxObj').subscribe( function(reduxObj){
               console.log(reduxObj);
               this.reduxObj = reduxObj;                              
    }.bind(this)); 
}
```

Comment: why are u using `bind`

Comment: if I use the callback without the  arrow I lost the context , that's why i m using bind(this)

Comment: use the arrow function  `.subscribe( (reduxObj) => {` and remove the bind

Comment: i have the same behavior.